# How to setup pytorch in google-cloud-ml

Tags: pytorch, google-cloud-ml

I try to throw job with `Pytorch` code in google-cloud-ml.
so I code the "setup.py" file. And add option "install_requires"

"setup.py"

```python
from setuptools import find_packages
from setuptools import setup
REQUIRED_PACKAGES = ['http://download.pytorch.org/whl/cpu/torch-0.3.0.post4-cp27-cp27mu-linux_x86_64.whl','torchvision']

setup(
    name='trainer',
    version='0.1',
    install_requires=REQUIRED_PACKAGES,
    packages=find_packages(),
    include_package_data=True,
    description='My keras trainer application package.'
)
```

and throw the job to the google-cloud-ml, but it doesn't work

## with error message

```python
{
 insertId:  "3m78xtf9czd0u"  
 jsonPayload: {
  created:  1516845879.49039   
  levelname:  "ERROR"   
  lineno:  829   
  message:  "Command '['pip', 'install', '--user', '--upgrade', '--force-reinstall', '--no-deps', u'trainer-0.1.tar.gz']' returned non-zero exit status 1"   
  pathname:  "/runcloudml.py"   
 }
 labels: {
  compute.googleapis.com/resource_id:  "6637909247101536087"   
  compute.googleapis.com/resource_name:  "cmle-training-master-5502b52646-0-ql9ds"   
  compute.googleapis.com/zone:  "us-central1-c"   
  ml.googleapis.com/job_id:  "run_ml_engine_pytorch_test_20180125_015752"   
  ml.googleapis.com/job_id/log_area:  "root"   
  ml.googleapis.com/task_name:  "master-replica-0"   
  ml.googleapis.com/trial_id:  ""   
 }
 logName:  "projects/exem-191100/logs/master-replica-0"  
 receiveTimestamp:  "2018-01-25T02:04:55.421517460Z"  
 resource: {
  labels: {…}   
  type:  "ml_job"   
 }
 severity:  "ERROR"  
 timestamp:  "2018-01-25T02:04:39.490387916Z"  
}
```

====================================================================

[See detailed message here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s2oSw.png)

so how can i use pytorch in google cloud ml engine?

Comment: Can you add messages as text? It is not very convenient to read it from pictures, and it prevents searching engines from indexing information effectively. Also, pictures may expires some day.

Comment: sorry... transfer to the text

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i find solution about setting up **PYTORCH** in **google-cloud-ml**

**first**
you have to get a `.whl` file about pytorch and store it to google storage bucket.
and you will get the link for bucket link.

```python
gs://bucketname/directory/torch-0.3.0.post4-cp27-cp27mu-linux_x86_64.whl
```

the `.whl` file is depend on your python version or cuda version....

**second**
you write the command line and setup.py because you have to set up the google-cloud-ml setting.
related link is this  [submit_job_to_ml-engine](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/ml-engine/jobs/submit/training)
you write the `setup.py` file to describe your setup.
the related link is this [write_setup.py_file](https://cloud.google.com/ml-engine/docs/versioning#to_provide_package_files)

this is my command code and setup.py file

=====================================================================
 **"command"**

```python
#commandline code
JOB_NAME="run_ml_engine_pytorch_test_$(date +%Y%m%d_%H%M%S)"
REGION=us-central1
OUTPUT_PATH=gs://yourbucket
gcloud ml-engine jobs submit training $JOB_NAME \
    --job-dir $OUTPUT_PATH \
    --runtime-version 1.4 \
    --module-name models.pytorch_test \
    --package-path models/ \
    --packages gs://yourbucket/directory/torch-0.3.0.post4-cp27-cp27mu-linux_x86_64.whl \
    --region $REGION \
    -- \
    --verbosity DEBUG
```

=====================================================================
**"setup.py"**

```python
from setuptools import find_packages
from setuptools import setup
REQUIRED_PACKAGES = ['torchvision']
setup(
    name='trainer',
    version='0.1',
    install_requires=REQUIRED_PACKAGES,
    packages=find_packages(),
    include_package_data=True,
    description='My pytorch trainer application package.'
)
```

=====================================================================

**third**
if you have experience submitting job to the ml-engine.
you might know the file structure about submitting ml-engine
[packaging_training_model](https://cloud.google.com/ml-engine/docs/packaging-trainer).
you have to follow above link and know how to pack files.

Answer (score 0):

The actual error message is a bit buried, but it is this:

> 'install_requires' must be a string or list of strings containing
>   valid project/version requirement specifiers; Invalid requirement,
>   parse error at "'://downl'"

To use packages not hosted on PyPI, you need to use `dependency_links` (see [this](http://python-packaging.readthedocs.io/en/latest/dependencies.html#packages-not-on-pypi) documentation). Something like this ought to work:

```
from setuptools import find_packages
from setuptools import setup

REQUIRED_PACKAGES = ['torchvision']
DEPENDENCY_LINKS = ['http://download.pytorch.org/whl/cpu/torch-0.3.0.post4-cp27-cp27mu-linux_x86_64.whl']

setup(
    name='trainer',
    version='0.1',
    install_requires=REQUIRED_PACKAGES,
    dependency_links=DEPENDENCY_LINKS,
    packages=find_packages(),
    include_package_data=True,
    description='My keras trainer application package.'
)
```

Comment: thanks... but it's not work anyway...
the error message

  "Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-_ZQ7aQ/torch/"