# In google-cloud-ml, setup.py error during setting up PYTORCH

Tags: pytorch, google-cloud-ml

i write **setup.py** like below to setup pytorch in google-cloud-ml engine

```
from setuptools import find_packages
from setuptools import setup
REQUIRED_PACKAGES = ['torchvision']
DEPENDENCY_LINKS =['http://download.pytorch.org/whl/cpu/torch-0.3.0.post4-cp27-cp27mu-linux_x86_64.whl']
setup(
    name='trainer',
    version='0.1',
    dependency_links=DEPENDENCY_LINKS,
    install_requires=REQUIRED_PACKAGES,
    packages=find_packages(),
    include_package_data=True,
    description='My pytorch trainer application package.'
)
```

**error message**

```
"Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-_ZQ7aQ/torch/"
```

i don't know what it happen....
when i searched about that problem... the answers are just upgrade the setuptools... but i don't know how to upgrade setuptools in ml-engine...

so please help me...!
i want to run pytorch code in ml engine

Answer (score 2):

Seems like DEPENDENCY_LINKS has been ignored by pip.
Instead, I copied the whl file to a GCS bucket, and used the flag '--package gs://my-bucket/torch-0.3.0.post4-cp27-cp27mu-linux_x86_64.whl' in gcloud to install the whl file before executing 'pip install torchvision' and it worked.

You also need to remove DEPENDENCY_LINKS from setup.py

```
from setuptools import find_packages
from setuptools import setup
REQUIRED_PACKAGES = ['torchvision']
setup(
    name='trainer',
    version='0.1',
    install_requires=REQUIRED_PACKAGES,
    packages=find_packages(),
    include_package_data=True,
    description='My pytorch trainer application package.'
)
```

Comment: thanks! i found the solution and answer to my last question.https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48434556/how-to-setup-pytorch-in-google-cloud-ml/48615760#48615760