# " gcloud beta ai-platform versions create" fails with private URI dependency

Tags: google-cloud-platform, dependencies, gcloud, google-ai-platform

Executing:

```
gcloud beta ai-platform versions create $VERSION_NAME \
  --model $MODEL_NAME \
  --runtime-version 2.3 \
  --python-version 3.7 \
  --origin gs://$BUCKET_NAME/dummy/v1/model/ \
  --package-uris gs://$BUCKET_NAME/dummy/v1/dummy_diagnostic_model-0.1.tar.gz \
  --prediction-class predictor.MyPredictor
```

Results in:

```
ERROR: (gcloud.beta.ai-platform.versions.create) Create Version failed. Bad model detected with error:  "Failed to load model: Unexpected error when loading the model: No module named 'k' (Error code: 0)"
```

Running this locally succeeds:

```
pip install  --upgrade --target=/tmp/custom_lib --no-cache-dir -b /tmp/pip_builds dist/dummy_diagnostic_model-0.1.tar.gz
```

I guess this issue is about gitlab access token not configured on gcloud machine, how can i resolve this issue?

Comment: Can you try the workaround in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48512588/in-google-cloud-ml-setup-py-error-during-setting-up-pytorch?

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a dependency issue. Make sure to follow [Package your Predictor and its dependencies](https://cloud.google.com/ai-platform/prediction/docs/custom-prediction-routines#predictor-tarball) documentation, as **No module named** error is usually caused by not creating the *preprocess.py*, *predictor.py*, and *setup.py* files  all in the same directory.

For more details, make sure to check this previous [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61933879/11866133) and this [article](https://medium.com/@aftaabzia9/serverless-machine-learning-deployment-with-pytorch-and-google-cloud-f89775773b6b).

Comment: They are all packaged together, `but preprocess.py` imports from an external package that is located under a private PyPI url, so this is my `setup.py` file:

`
...
setup(
    name='dummy_diagnostic_model',
    version='0.1',
    dependency_links=['PRIVATE_GITLAB_PYPI_URL',
    ],
    scripts=['predictor.py', 'preprocess.py', 'postprocess.py'])

`




To download a package from the private url a gitlab access token has to be configured somewhere, not sure how though